# How to round SelectedItemBackground on click item like this image

Tags: android

[Here I indicate with red arrow that I want to create possible. By default Selecteditembackground is not rounded on android. But I need to make it rounded like this Image . How ???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzKw1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I would create 2 Images for my button. One without a backround and one with backround. Then I would use a ToggleButton and would assign my two images for the two states checked an unchecked. You could also use a regular ImageButton for that and switch between the images onClick. By doing so you can create every design you wish.